# How do I call API using postman for requesting token for large scale matrix routing in HERE API

Tags: postman, here-api

I am not able to figure out the exact API request format in Postman for requesting token for large scale matrix routing in HERE API. Below is the official document page which is not clear of course.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/large-matrix/dev_guide/topics/get-started/request-a-token.html

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to using the Large-Scale Matrix Routing API is to first generate an OAuth 1.0 signature using your `access key id` and `access key secret`. See this page for how to create the credentials:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/token.html

See how you can generate your signature and use the signature to request a token:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-aaa-javasdk-or-3rd-party-libraries.html#using-aaa-javasdk-or-3rd-party-libraries

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have done both already. Main concern is, how do i call REST API to get token using Postman?

Comment: Check this https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-postman.html

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport  After following all this steps still getting this error in postman ~  "error_description": "errorCode: '401202'. Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format."